# Newey West Covariance in SAS and in R are different

Tags: r, regression, sas, neweywest

I am using the `proc autoreg` procedure in SAS and the `sandwich` library in R to calculate Newey West covariance for a linear model. The two methods give the same coefficient estimates (expected because they are OLS estimators), but different t-statistics hence p-values. Below is my code for model summary in R:

```
library(sandwich)
model = lm(response ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6,data=SAS_Q)
coeftest(model, vocv=NeweyWest(model,lag=2, prewhite=FALSE))
```

Below is my code to generate model summary in SAS:

```
proc autoreg data= SAS_Q plots=all;
    model response = var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6/covest=neweywest;;
    ods output ParameterEstimates = _auto_full_params_;
    output out=Autoreg_Out p=FORECAST_t rm=r pm=pm lcl=lcl lclm=lclm ucl=ucl uclm=uclm;
run;
quit;
```

No matter how I assign the lag, I can not get the R result to match that of the SAS. More specifically, the p-value for var5 is 0.11 in R but 0.03 in SAS. It also seems that my R-output is quite immune to the change of lag.

Am I doing anything wrong in R? If so, what is it?

Comment: `vocv` should be `vcov` - if what you post here is copy & paste from your code, then R cannot really have taken that part of the code into account (I would expect it to throw an error so that you do not get a result at all, but I'm not sure). Would be easier to answer if we got to see actual results.

Comment: Thank you Christoph! I corrected the mistake you pointed out and found that R is close to SAS, i.e., p-values agree to the first 3 decimal points,  when choosing lag=2. It is quite interesting that R did not throw an error with my vocv. No wonder I keep getting a covariance matrix very close to (in fact identical to) OLS. Thank you so much! If you post your comment as an answer I will accept.

Comment: did so, also because adding a little detail on `lmtest` may be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vocv` should be `vcov` - `R` cannot take that part of the code into account. I would have expected `R` to throw an error so that you do not get a result at all, or at least a warning, but that does not seem to be the case:

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest) # note this is needed for coeftest
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rnorm(100)
model <- lm(y ~ x)
coeftest(model) # default OLS setting
coeftest(model, vocv=NeweyWest(model,lag=2, prewhite=FALSE)) # with typo - same results as default
coeftest(model, vcov=NeweyWest(model,lag=2, prewhite=FALSE)) # without typo - different results (only slightly so here as my data does not have autocorrelation so that HAC standard erros are not necessary
```

returns

```
    > coeftest(model)

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.0687659  0.1041773 -0.6601   0.5107
x            0.0068797  0.0991511  0.0694   0.9448

> coeftest(model, vocv=NeweyWest(model,lag=2, prewhite=FALSE))

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.0687659  0.1041773 -0.6601   0.5107
x            0.0068797  0.0991511  0.0694   0.9448

> coeftest(model, vcov=NeweyWest(model,lag=2, prewhite=FALSE))

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.0687659  0.1075861 -0.6392   0.5242
x            0.0068797  0.0808703  0.0851   0.9324
```

I am not sufficiently skilled in R to give an authoritative answer (nor am I sure it is on topic for CV), but the underlying issue seems to be the combined presence of default values for existing arguments combined with `...` allowing for additional arguments to be passed on.

Consider

```
ExampleFuncWithAdditionalArguments <- function(xy=0,...){
  xy^2
}
ExampleFuncWithAdditionalArguments(xy=5)
ExampleFuncWithAdditionalArguments(xz=5)
```

which returns

```
> ExampleFuncWithAdditionalArguments(xy=5)
[1] 25
> ExampleFuncWithAdditionalArguments(xz=5)
[1] 0
```

The first call is as intended, the second has a typo. R then interprets the argument `xz` as an additional argument, with which the function however does nothing and `ExampleFuncWithAdditionalArguments` falls back to the default `xy=0`.

Comment: It happen because the coeftest function in R hasn't implemented argument matching